# PHPmailer - 500 internal server error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I keep on having the 500 internal sever error with my web hosted by GoDaddy, using the PHPmailer; I've tried several solutions available on StackOverflow relating to my challenge, but none of them worked.

Here is my code:

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$feedback='';
$flag = array();
if(isset($_POST["submitlogin"]) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    $name = seo_friendly_url($_POST['name']);
    $email = seo_friendly_url($_POST['email']);
    $subject = seo_friendly_url($_POST['subject']);
    $message = seo_friendly_url($_POST['message']);

    //Email

    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
        $feedback="Invalid email format";
        array_push($flag,"false");
    }else {
        array_push($flag,"true");
    }
    //Email 

    //Name
    if (preg_match('/^[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/', $name)){  
        array_push($flag,"true");
    }else {
        $feedback="Invalid name format";
        array_push($flag,"false");
    }
    //Name


    if (!in_array("false", $flag)) {

        //SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
        //This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
        date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();
        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        //Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net";
        //Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
        $mail->Port = 25;
        //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        //$mail->Username = 'email@email.com'; 
        //$mail->Password = 'password'; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->setFrom('email@email.com');
        //Set an alternative reply-to address
        $mail->addReplyTo($email);
        //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->addAddress('email@email.com');     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress('email@email.com');
        $mail->addAddress('email@email.com);
        //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = 'HLS Inquiry';
        //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
        //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
        $mail->msgHTML($message);







        $email_ar = $email;
        $subject_ar = $name.", Thank you for your Inquiry"; 
        $acknowledgement_receipt = '
            <div style="padding:10px 20px;font-size:16px;">

                <p>Dear '.$name.',</p>

                <p>We&#39;ve received your message and would like to thank you for contacting us. We will reply by email shortly.</p>

                <p>Talk to you soon,</p>

                <p>
                    <div>Customer Service</div>

                </p>

            </div>
        ';



        if ($mail->send()) {
            $feedback = "<span style='color:green;'>Thank you for your inquiry. We will respond to you within 24 hours.</span>";
        } 

}
```

Please note that I replaced some of the email values as: `email@email.com` for my privacy.

I believed that the email setups are correct because I already used those setups from my friend's website hosted by JustHost.

Comment: try to replace addAddress('email@email.com') with double quotes -> addAddress("email@email.com")

Answer (score 0):

This line is missing a single quote:

```
$mail->addAddress('email@email.com);
```

This is quite obvious in SO because you can see how the syntax highlighting breaks at that point.

When you get an error 500 and nothing is displayed, it's a sign that you should be looking in your web server's error log.

Comment: I tried putting the missing single quote, but still didn't work :(

where could i see the servers log?

Comment: Usually in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "split" function used to write the PHPMailer class. This function has been long deprecated and as such gives error in later PHP versions.
Find them and replace with "explode".
This worked for me.